# Perception at relatavistic speeds

Tags: special-relativity

If one were to be traveling at near the speed of light, their mass would be $m_{rel}= m_0 / \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$.  For the mass to double the speed would have to be $86.6\%c$

[edit]
To better phrase the question, perhaps I should use relativistic momentum: $p_{rel}=m_0v/\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$

In a space ship at this speed in zero gravity & acceleration, the mass would be weightless anyway.  But to swing ones arm left and right, would it seem to have more inertia to move in the direction of travel ?  Or does relativistic time compensate this and although the arm moves slower the perception of time corrects this and it appears to move as it should with the same effort?

Comment: Relativistic mass was a bad idea when it was introduced. Today, most physicists would tell you to ignore it. It was a short-sighted interpretation meant to make things easier to grasp and has, instead, only ended up confusing many people. Mass of the object does not actually increase. That is an artifact of the equation. It is the momentum that increases, not the mass

Comment: If the momentum goes non-linear, does the inertia change?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. Inertia is the property that is described by Newton's first law. It doesn't have a value. When the momentum goes non-linear, the object still has inertia. But it doesn't make sense to ask if the inertia changes. It simply has inertia

Comment: On relativistic scales $F\ne ma$

Answer (score 2):

From the reference frame of the space ship, your body is stationary. When you swing your arm back and forth, it has a non-zero speed in this frame, and thus its mass, or rather momentum, increases. The space ship's velocity of $v_\mathrm{ship} = 0.866c$ doesn't add to this. That means that the increase in momentum is exactly the same as if you swing your arm right now, on Earth. Thus, you can perform the experiment yourself, and verify that the momentum-increase is negligible. It *is* there, nonetheless.

From the reference frame of an observer that sees the space ship passing by at $0.866c$, the ship, your body, and your arm has increased their momenta by a factor of 2. When you swing your arm, its velocity will alternate between being slightly below $v_\mathrm{ship}$, and slightly above $v_\mathrm{ship}$. Hence, the observer will measure your arm's increase in momentum $\Delta p_\mathrm{arm}$ to be slightly below 2, and slightly above 2.

Note that velocities at this speed don't add like this
$$v_\mathrm{tot} = v_\mathrm{ship} + v_\mathrm{arm},\qquad\mathrm{(wrong!)}$$
but like this
$$v_\mathrm{tot} = \frac{v_\mathrm{ship} + v_\mathrm{arm}}{1+(v_\mathrm{ship} v_\mathrm{arm}/c^2)}.$$

EDIT: Also, note that what increases is not really mass, but rather *momentum*, as pointed out by @Jimnosperm. The argument is the same, though.

Comment: My question was not about the mass increase due to the incremental change in speed by moving ones arm.  It was if there would be an increased perception in inertia WRT rest.  If a 1kg block of lead is now 2kg, will more force be required to move it in the same amount of time?

Comment: Yes, but in the reference frame of you body, your arm, or the 1 kg block, or whatever's inside the space ship, does _not_ move at relativistic velocities, so moving your arm doesn't require more force than doing the same experiment on Earth.

Comment: @Michael What you are doing now is trying to combine Newtonian mechanics and special relativity. You can't do that. Inside the ship, the force will be the same. Outside the ship, the force will be the same. Both will cause the same increase in momentum. The difference is just that outside the ship, the difference in velocity of the arms will be less than inside the ship

Comment: Just for the benefit of the readers, I would like to add that the non-intuitive formula at the end of the post is the relativistic (i.e. non-Gallilean) velocity composition law. Those non-familiar with this can read more about it here: http://www.mth.uct.ac.za/omei/gr/chap1/node12.html